# Modify the Http Status Code text

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, asp.net-web-api2, http-status-codes

**Question**

How to modify the Status Code text (description/title)?

**Example**

For example: I want to change `200 (Ok)` to `200 (My Custom Text)`

**Desciption**

I want to create a HTTP response with custom Status Code (unreserved) 431. I want to modify it's text:

- `200 (OK)`
- `400 (Bad Request)`
- `431 (My message here)`

**I've tried:**

```
var response = new HttpResponseMessage() 
{
    StatusCode = (HttpStatusCode) 431,
};

response.Headers.Add("Status Code", "431 My custom text"); // This throws error.
```

Comment: What error is thrown?

Comment: `The header name format is invalid.`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just add ReasonPhrase in initializer :

```
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage()
        {
            StatusCode = (HttpStatusCode)431,
            ReasonPhrase = "your text"
        };
```

It defines text of the message that send with the status code

Answer (score 2):

One way to solve this issue is to skip the validation of the header you add. This can be done with the [TryAddWithoutValidation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh875107%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) method.

```
var response = new HttpResponseMessage() 
{
    StatusCode = (HttpStatusCode) 431,
};

response.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation ("Status Code", "431 My custom text");
```